# Cambiar Formato columna Getdate a date

Tags: sql, formato

Tengo una columna con `getdate()` cuyo tipo de datos es `datetime`, pero necesito que sea solo date para poder hacer una operación con otra columna.

He intentado hacer esto pero no hace ningún cambio.

```
select CONVERT (date, GETDATE()) as FechaActual from TBL_TR_MNGR_VCCNS
```

Necesito hacer una columna consultada con ese dato y esto intentando hacer esto

```
alter table TBL_TR_MNGR_VCCNS
add DiasAdquiridos as((FechaActual - FechaIngreso)*15/365)
```

`FechaActual` es la columna con el `getdate`
`FechaIngreso` es una columna tipo de datos date.

No se que hacer... Ayuda!!

Comment: Es `TBL_TR_MNGR_VCCNS` realmente una tabla?, cómo tienes una columna con `GETDATE`  ahí?

Comment: TBL_TR_MNGR_VCCNS es el nombre de la tabla. La columna con el GETDATE se llama FechaActual

Comment: Pero una tabla no puede tener una columna que sea una función no determinística...(asumiendo SQL Server, qué motor de base de datos estás usando)

Comment: Que pena, es que soy nueva en esto de la programación. de verdad no sé como hacer porque necesito realizar una columna consultada pero me sale este error.
FechaActual = campo computed, es decir trae la fecha del sistema con GETDATE().
FechaIngreso = campo datetime, donde se insertan datos.

Comment: No me queda claro si lo que quieres es obtener los datos de la columna como date en un select, o convertir la columna a tipo Date

Comment: ¿Es posible que lo que necesitas realmente es realizar una consulta en vez de modificar la tabla?

Comment: a ver  si te entendí lo que requieres es asignar el resultado ((FechaActual - FechaIngreso)*15/365) a tu campo DiasAdquiridos?

Comment: si, necesito obtener el resultado de esta operación:  ((FechaActual - FechaIngreso)*15/365) en el campo DiasAdquiridos

Answer (score 0):

Si tus campos son de tipo `date` o `datetime` entonces solo hay que realizar la operación en el `select`.

Ejemplo:

```
select (DATEDIFF(DAY,FechaIngreso,GETDATE())*15/365) as DiasAdquiridos from TBL_TR_MNGR_VCCNS
```

`DATEDIFF` realiza la operación ya sea con valores `datetime` o `date`

`GETDATE()` puede sustituirse por FechaActual

Comment: Ya intente hacer esto, pero me sale este error: El tipo de datos date del operando no es válido para el operador subtract.

Comment: Yo lo que necesito hacer es calcular los días de vacaciones adquiridos de los empleados, eso se calcula asi: (fecha actual - fecha ingreso)*15/365 no sé como hacerlo, porque cree una columna FechaActual con GETDATE cuyo tipo de datos es datetime, y tengo otra columna FechaIngreso que tiene tipo de datos date. @Juan

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que intentas hacer es calcular el tirmpo transcurrido entre dos fechas, la mejor opción es hacerlo con la función `DATEDIFF`.

```
DiasAdquiridos as(DATEDIFF(day, Convert(date, FechaActual), FechaIngreso)*15/365)
```

o el equivalente, en tu caso

```
DiasAdquiridos as(DATEDIFF(day, Convert(date, GetDate()), FechaIngreso)*15/365)
```

Para la primera opción, deberías tener configurada la columna FechaActual como la imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Yo lo que necesito hacer es calcular los días de vacaciones adquiridos de los empleados, eso se calcula asi: (fecha actual - fecha ingreso)*15/365 no sé como hacerlo, porque cree una columna FechaActual con GETDATE cuyo tipo de datos es datetime, y tengo otra columna FechaIngreso que tiene tipo de datos date.

Comment: Edité la respuesta, esto debe funcionar.

Comment: La columna calculada 'FechaActual' de la tabla 'TBL_TR_MNGR_VCCNS' no se puede usar en otra definición de columna calculada.

Comment: Primero, Si FechaActual no debería ser una columna calculada, debería tener como valor predeterminado el GetDate(). Segundo, si FechaActual equivale a GetDate() entondes sustituye en el script FechaActual por GetDate()

Comment: es decir que no puedo hacer operaciones entre columnas calculadas? si es así, que otra manera hay para poder hacer estas operaciones?

Comment: He vuelto a editar la respuesta, en la imagen podrás ver como debe ser, si lo que quieres es que cuando se inserte la fila, el valor de la FechaActual sea GetDate(). Si lo que quieres es que siempre sea la fecha de ahora, toma la segunda opción.